# Unable to use a c# reference after adding it

Tags: c#, reference, project

so I am completely dumbfounded by this problem! I believe I have added my C# references correctly, but for some reason, my Domain projects are not being intellisensed.

[Here is an example of other references working fine,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J96qW.png)

[And here's an example of the domain references not working.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLChL.png)

To me this is a fairly simple mechanism of C# and I'm not sure why it works for one set of projects and not another.

Comment: what is it warning message? maybe dublicate dictionary names

Comment: Hey, so the error message is 'The type or namespace name 'Entities' does not exist in the namespace 'Domain' (are you missing an assembly reference?)'` However, when I just have `using Domain;` I get no errors.

Comment: Intellisense should help... Pay attention to possible typos. Note that the name of one of the references is "Domain.Entites" (not "Entities", notice the missing second `i`). It could be that the same typo has been made for the type/namespace name(s) ...

Comment: Your reference is misspelled. Entities vs Enitites

Comment: Hey Ben, so the intellisense does not work at all. I get the same error when I spell it correctly.

Comment: Joe, double-click on the "Domain.Entites" reference. This should open the object browser for that assembly. Check if the assembly (or the other Domain.* assembly you referenced) actually contains the namespace you are trying to use.

Comment: elgonzo, I've looked in there and it appears to have the classes that I want.

Comment: What exactly is the namespace of those classes in that assembly? Is it really "Domain.Entities"?

Comment: Hey, I'll post an imgur link to that part of the solution https://i.imgur.com/R1ZESqi.png

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately that screenshot does not really show anything relevant about the namespaces you have a problem with. Perhaps show a screenshot of the object browser showing the class(es) (including namespace) you want to use from the "Domain.Entites" assembly...

Comment: If it helps, I also just checked the error logs and there are these suspicious errors https://i.imgur.com/F7BrFIo.png

Comment: And here is the object explorer screenshot. https://i.imgur.com/8IZktO9.png

Comment: Okay, note that the namespace has the same typo as the reference. The namespace is NOT "Domain.Entities", but rather "Domain.Entites". If you use the correct namespace (the one with the typo), what happens?

Comment: Voting to close as the issue was a typo and this post is not likely to help other users.

Answer (score 0):

If it still compiles and it really is just intelli sense:
1. Close visual Studio
2. Move into the project dir
3. Delete the `.vs` folder

Afterwards, it should work

Comment: Hey so I did all of that and it's still not building.

Comment: As I noted: if it really is just intelli sense, and it compile, that will fix cache issues. As it does not compiles, your Problem is not intelli sense based. Check if the namespace actually exists in your assembly and double Check naming plus encapsulation